# Playing audio files from desired folder

Tags: android, audio, directory, media-player, kotlin

I have 5 folders and every folder contains 5 audio files. When Someone clicks on a folder, The program should start playing all the audio files  from that folder.
I am new to android, So i have a very little Idea about it.
I tried doing it, but it shows all the audio files together.
I want it to show folder wise.

```
fun abs(){

    var songsURI = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    var selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0"
    val cursor = contentResolver.query(songsURI,null,selection,null,null)
    if(cursor!= null)
    {
        if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()){

            do
            {
                var songURL = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
                        var songAuth =cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
                                var SongNAme = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
                listSongs.add(Songinfo(songURL,songAuth,SongNAme))

            }while (cursor!!.moveToNext())
        }
        cursor!!.close()

        adapter = MySongAdapter(listSongs)
        hello.adapter = adapter
    }


}
```

Please Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will give you the list of songs in each directory, you should change the adapter to show the directory name and the song list.

```
data class SongInfo(var songURL: String, var songAuth: String, var songNAme: String)
data class DirInfo(var dir: String, var songInfo: ArrayList<SongInfo>)

private fun getAudioDirectories(): ArrayList<DirInfo> {

    var result = ArrayList<DirInfo>()

    val directories = LinkedHashMap<String, ArrayList<SongInfo>>()

    val uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI
    val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + "!=0"

    val order = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_MODIFIED + " DESC"

    val cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, selection, null, order)

    cursor.let {
        it.moveToFirst()

        val pathIndex = it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)

        do {
            val path = it.getString(pathIndex)

            val file = File(path)
            if (!file.exists()) {
                continue
            }

            val fileDir = file.getParent()

            var songURL = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
            var songAuth = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
            var songName = it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))

            if (directories.containsKey(fileDir)) {
                var songs = directories.getValue(fileDir);

                var song = SongInfo(songURL, songAuth, songName)

                songs.add(song)

                directories.put(fileDir, songs)
            } else {
                var song = SongInfo(songURL, songAuth, songName)

                var songs = ArrayList<SongInfo>()
                songs.add(song)

                directories.put(fileDir, songs)
            }
        } while (it.moveToNext())


        for (dir in directories) {
            var dirInfo: DirInfo = DirInfo(dir.key, dir.value);

            result.add(dirInfo)
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Using your Adapter we can't show list of Album with songs list, you can use [this](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/265) or you can take any of these libs from [Android-Arsenal](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/54?sort=created)

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer,

Comment: I am facing problem with adapter

Comment: Updated my answer, If your problem solved to get the list of albums with the relevant songs list,  accept my answer.

Comment: I Wrote the adapter class but my screen is not splaying anything

Comment: You can add your adapter class in your question, so that i can look into that.

Comment: Can you help me with the adapters, with arsenal, I am unable to do